# Any limitation on number of rewarded ads on mobile app

Tags: admob, adsense, rewardedvideoad, admob-rewardedvideoad

I'm developing a mobile app which allows the users to add posts. To add posts, users required some 'diamonds'. User can earn diamonds when they signup, collect daily diamonds and by watching Google reward ad.

When a user reached insufficient number of diamonds when adding a post, I'm showing a button named "watch this advertisement and earn 5 diamonds', the user will earn 5 diamonds by watching and then he can post.

This same user can watch this rewarded ads again and again on the same day and earn diamonds and post several posts in a day.

Is this allowed by Google Adsense? ie, allowing users to view rewarded ad multiple times in a short period? What is the limitation ?

NOTE : We are giving the option to the users can earn diamonds on a daily basis also. And we are not forcing the users to post all the posts in one single day. They have option to post them on different days.

Comment: Did you implemented this and does it has any issues (from Google side)?

Answer (score 1):

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9121589?hl=en shows rules on rewarded ads.

Nowhere on that page does Google state any limitation on the amount of rewarded ads that can be shown to users per certain amount of time. **Looks like you're good.**

The only limitation is that users need to opt to see each ad, individually, as per the link mentioned earlier:

> *"Rewarded ads may only be served after a user affirmatively opts to view a rewarded ad. Additionally, a user must opt to view each
> rewarded ad individually and cannot opt-in to automatically seeing
> rewarded ads." (From AdSense Help)*